# Using two tables to get one report in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `product` and `download` as follows.

- `product` (product_id (pk), product_name)
- `download` (download_date(pk), download_version(pk), product_id(pk,fk))

I need a report to show how many downloaded, form which version of what product took place in each month.

```
SELECT 
    [product_name],
    [version],
    MONTH(download_date) AS [Month],
    COUNT(MONTH(download_date)) AS [Count]  
FROM
    product 
INNER JOIN 
    download ON product.product_id = download.product_id 
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(download_date)
```

and I get this error

> Column 'product.product_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use alias names for the tables for better readability.
2. Mention the aliasname.columnname in the SELECT to avoid fetching the wrong values.
3. You missed the other columns except the aggregate values in the GROUP BY.

So the query below will return the result.

```
SELECT P.[product_name],
      P.[version],
      MONTH(D.download_date) AS [Month],
      COUNT(MONTH(D.download_date)) AS [Count]  
FROM product P
INNER JOIN download D ON D.product_id = P.product_id 
GROUP BY P.[product_name], P.[version], MONTH(D.download_date)
```

Answer (score -2):

You have some issue with tables and primary key.

create the table like this.
product(product_id(PK),name,verion)
download(date,product_id)

and run this query

```
SELECT product.name,product.version,COUNT(download.product_id) 
FROM product INNER JOIN download ON product.product_id=download.download_id 
Group BY(download._productid);
```

i think this is what you want if not post replay i will answer when i get back to stack.

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work but I used INNER JOIN idea and mad some changes which are not working again